# Flot (time data), xaxis - disappeared labels if there are more data

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

My Chart looks like this and I like it (xaxis has in turn: Feb3, Feb4, Feb5 etc):

[CHART OK](http://ulewa.com/img/flot1.jpg)

But when I add more time data, every second month is disappear:
(there will not be much more data, every month will fit in! but it gone..)

[CHART WRONG](http://ulewa.com/img/flot2.jpg)

I want to have displayed every month like on first image..
I can't wider my placeholder:

```
<div id="placeholder1" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

(it must have 700px)

**My code:**

```
var data = [

    [1328223600000, 5],
    [1328310000000, 15],
    [1328396400000, 30],
    [1328482800000, 17],
    [1328655600000, 7],
    [1328742000000, 33],
    [1328828400000, 40],
    [1328914800000, 22],
    [1329001200000, 40],
    [1329087600000, 33],
    [1329174000000, 33],

]; 

var ds = new Array();

ds.push({
    data:data,
    bars: {
        show: true, 
        align: "center",
        barWidth: 1000*60*60*24, 
        fill: true,
    },
    color: "#aae0f0",
});


$.plot($("#placeholder1"), ds, {

grid:{ hoverable:true, clickable: true },

xaxis:
{
    mode: "time",
    minTickSize: [1, "day"],

    font: {
         size: 7,
         style: "italic",
         weight: "bold",
         family: "sans-serif",
         variant: "small-caps"
       },

    tickLength: 0,
    alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
},

series:
 {
    //stack: 1, // - not work too
    //bandwidth: { active: true , lineWidth: 8 },
 }

});
```

Thanks in advance for any reply.

PS. Why my **font: {}** method is not working too? :(

*// I'm not English native speaker so please forgive me gramma mestakes.*

Answer (score 1):

Your font options don't work because Flot doesn't support those options; search the [API docs](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt) for 'xaxis'.  You should instead set those in your CSS, under the .tickLabel class.

As for the labels disappearing, you can probably solve it by setting tickSize instead of minTickSize, but at a certain point your labels will overlap and start to look ugly.  Since Flot doesn't support rotated/multi-row labels, the only way to avoid that is to reduce the font size.

Comment: Essentially, font-size I get from API: http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt and there is section about styling font: { ... }.
So I dont know how to style it because  <style>.tickLabels { font-size: 8px;} </style> not work.
With **TickSize: [1, "day"]** not work eather :(

Comment: I see; you're using trunk.  The font options in trunk are related to canvas text support, and are very experimental.  Can you try .tickLabels with the 0.7 release?

Comment: Yes, I using newest version of Flot - 0.7 and simple styling ..tickLabels not work:/

Comment: I just tried it against one of the official examples, and it works fine; are you sure your CSS is correct, and is being included?

Comment: Och my.. I write ".tickLabel**s**" (with "s") lol
Now it works, but smaller font still not resolve my main problem with blank labels :/
DNS, thanks for your time anyway.